# I am looking for concatenating in the excel file and output should be in text file

Tags: python

My Data looks like the below in Excel file, want to import this inputfile in python and output file should be in text file

```
A      B   C
APPLE  A1  A
BALL   B2  B
CAT        C
DOG
```

Output should be the like this

```
Apple A1 A
Apple A1 B
Apple A1 C
Apple B2 A
Apple B2 B
Apple B2 C
Ball  A1 A
Ball  A1 B
Ball  A1 C
Ball  B2 A
Ball  B2 B
Ball  B2 C
Cat   A1 A
Cat   A1 B
Cat   A1 C
Cat   B2 A
Cat   B2 B
Cat   B2 C
```

Comment: Is your input a .xslx file or a .csv file? If you can, I recommend using a .csv file which is easier to work with than a .xslx file.

Comment: Yes, CSV file will do

Comment: import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Misc/input_file.csv')
df['Output'] = df['Name'] + ' + ' + df['Interval'] + ' + ' + df['FACT']

output_string = '\n'.join(df['Output'])
with open('C:/Misc/output_file.txt', 'w') as f:
f.write(output_string)


I tried with the above its not working

Comment: Don't post code in comments.  Please edit the question and add the code there, and also explain what the actual problem is.  Saying "it didn't work" is not much of a description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some inspiration you can adjust for your specifics. The example assumes the "Excel" data is stored in a `.csv` file as you mentioned was OK in a comment.

You seem to want to get the Cartesian product of the values in the three columns, which this will do. Doesn't use pandas but you can do that if you want.

```
from itertools import product  # Cartesian product
import csv

# Get columns from csv into seperate lists, only using non-empty entires
with open("csv_filename.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

    cols_without_empty = []
    for i in range(3):
        next(reader)  # Ignore header row
        cols_without_empty.append([row[i] for row in reader if row[i]])
        f.seek(0)


# Get all possible combinations of the columns, and write to output.txt
with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in product(*cols_without_empty):
        f.write("\t".join(i) + "\n")
```

Notice the `*cols_without_empty`. The `*` unpacks the list of lists into "separate arguments" to be passed to `product`.

This doesn't turn APPLE into Apple etc. like you wrote in your question though, since I assume that was a mistake. Furthermore, it includes the Dog-combinations, which your question doesn't show.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this.
I see the next (reader) is ignoring only the Column1 and not from the Column2 and Column3

Comment: Sorry, my bad. A simple solution is just to add `next(reader)` after each of the two `f.seek(0)`, or better yet, turn it into a for loop. Will update my answer

Comment: Perfect :)
Thanks a lot. Working as expected